# Pass multiple Spark job parameters in Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I want to pass multiple spark properties in glue job like :

```
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true
spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled =true
```

I am passing these parameters in glue job as below :

```
Key  spark.sql.adaptive.enabled       value  true
Key spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled   value  true
```

Just want to confirm, is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

well, I think below is the right way to add the parameters that you mentioned:

```
Key: --conf
Value: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true
```

please refer to the final part of the document :
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-no-spaces-on-device-error

Hope it helps